# Filter records in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL table as Follows

```
buyer   seller  qty price
A          B    100 4.2
A          B    200 4.3
A          C    50  4.2
W          Q    10  4.5
B          A    150 4.4
B          A    100 4.55
B          A    50  4.6
B          C    10  4.3
A          Q    40  4
F          M    20  4.25
L          B    30  4.50
```

Table contains trading information of a stock. here we can see there is connection between A and B. Most of the time A buys the stock from B and at each trade they increase the price slightly. In the same way B buys from A the same amount later for a higher price. I need to filter out such a connection from a select statement. How can I do it from a select statement.

I need to filter out the following results. Show a continuous relationship between A and B. This is a sample table, actual table contains more than 10,000 history trades   of all the clients with the given column names

```
buyer   seller  qty price
A          B    100 4.2
A          B    200 4.3
A          C    50  4.2
B          A    150 4.4
B          A    100 4.55
B          A    50  4.6
```

A and B are hypothetical values I need to show similar relationships from all 10,000 records. Not only A and B but of other buyers and sellers

Comment: [***What have you tried?***](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you want for results.

Comment: What do you mean by 'later'. There's no 'earlier' or 'later' here.

Comment: A and B are hypothetical values I need to show similar relationships from all 10,000 records. Not only A and B but of other buyers and sellers

Answer (score 0):

Could you do something as simple as:

```
SELECT *
FROM tablename
WHERE (buyer = 'A' AND seller = 'B') OR (buyer = 'B' AND seller = 'A')
```

Comment: A and B are hypothetical values I need to show similar relationships from all 10,000 records. Not only A and B but of other buyers and sellers